# What is the Strategy for Rotating MySQL 5.7 certs with Active/Passive Pool?

Tags: mysql-5.7, ssl

Aside from migrating while we upgrade to 8.0, which is an option, what have people done workflow/strategy to rollout and rotate MySQL SSL credentials with zero downtime?